# Object of type 'Infragistics.Web.UI.SlideFadeAnimation' cannot be converted to type 'Sys.Component'

Tags: javascript, infragistics

I am getting following Infragistics error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Infragistics.Web.UI.SlideFadeAnimation' cannot be converted to type 'Sys.Component'.
>   Parameter name: component

Error source is eval code's Infragistics.Web.UI.CalendarListAnimationStoppedEventArgs event.

```
function Sys$_Application$removeComponent(component) {
    /// <summary locid="M:J#Sys.Application.removeComponent" />
    /// <param name="component" type="Sys.Component"></param>
    var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
        {name: "component", type: Sys.Component}
    ]);
    if (e) throw e;
    var id = component.get_id();
    if (id) delete this._components[id];
}
```

Attempts: I've searched for Infragistics.Web.UI.SlideFadeAnimation in the entire solution and there was a single reference of it.

Any suggestion to solve the problem is much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using **WebMonthCalendar** control, and the issue is invoked on calendar animation stopped. Is it possible to share what is your code implementation, and at which point of the application lifecycle the error is shown.

Also information like browser, exact product version and general application configuration description would be helpful.

Comment: I will edit the question with my code and add the additional info as well. Thanks for the response.